# Proving that all polynomials are continuous

Tags: general-topology

Prove that all polynomials from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are continuous. Now this is from a topological point of view.

I thought that maybe induction would work here?

Initial Case: $f(x) = a_{0}$ where $a_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$. This is continuous.

Inductive Case: $f(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^2 + ... + a_{n}x^n + ...$

Since the sum of continuous functions is continuous, this implies every term is continuous. Makes sense. Feel like theirs a lot of holes in my reasoning though. For one I am not sure how to show the constant $a_{0}$ is continuous from a topological view.

Comment: The constant function is particularly easy: the inverse image of any open set $S$ is either the empty set or $\mathbb{R}$, depending on whether $a_0\in S$. Both of these are open.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways you can go about this, one approach might be from first principles prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous, then so is $xf(x) + c$.

Then consider the following iterations:

$$ p_0(x) = a_n $$
$$ p_1(x) = x p_0(x) + a_{n-1} $$
$$ p_2(x) = x p_1(x) + a_{n-2} $$
$$ \dots $$
$$ p_n(x) = f(x) $$

At each step you're multiplying a continuous function by $x$ and then adding a constant and so an inductive argument can go from there.

Comment: Your claim that each step is the composition of a linear function with a continuous function is incorrect.

Comment: Good point, i'll edit the answer